# Wait until Gmail email received

Tags: python, email, selenium, xpath

Currently have a gmail account with no emails in the inbox. I want to be able to display a popup with the current number of emails. If there are no emails, then no message is displayed.

So I'm choosing to use Explicit Waits & Xpath to do this. It's to my understanding that this allows me define a time period (say 10 s) and then each 500 ms, the code would query and check to see if the element contained the right text, as per specified by the second argument to the function below.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=':3s']/div/div[1]/span/a/"), 'Inbox (1)'))
```

The xpath location is the xpath of the Inbox button. It has a value that changes. (you can verify this in your own browser if you like)

I actually just ran it for the first time (ran it for the first time, after I posted, don't ask why) and got this error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/SG/Desktop/Report/Web_2.py", line 47, in <module>
   wait.until(EC.element_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=':3s']/div/div[1]/span/a/"), 'Inbox (1)'))
```

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'element_to_be_present_in_element'

After implementing:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=':3s']/div/div[1]/span/a[text()[contains(.,'Inbox (1)')]]")))
```

I'm still getting this error at compile:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/singhgurp/Desktop/Report/Web_2.py", line 51, in <module>
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=':3s']/div/div[1]/span/a[text()[contains(.,'Inbox (1)')]]")))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/SINGHG~1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq64vsuyi/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///C:/Users/SINGHG~1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq64vsuyi/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///C:/Users/SINGHG~1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq64vsuyi/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/SINGHG~1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq64vsuyi/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///C:/Users/SINGHG~1/AppData/Local/Temp/tmpq64vsuyi/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

The page has 1 email so it should work, not sure why it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=':3s']/div/div[1]/span/a"))
```

In selenium-python doc, there is no method `element_to_be_present_in_element` to check if there is any element as expected in the page, however doc refs the method `presence_of_element_located`.

Doc: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Sorry about that I was using the text_to_be_present_in_element, but i tried your code and had the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/singhgurp/Desktop/Report/Web_2.py", line 51, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=':3s']/div/div[1]/span/a/"), 'Inbox (1)'))
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Sorry, i forget to change the method arguments. Now, it will work. Also, what  `Inbox (1)` should do? Is the element text? Because if it is, you can put it inside the xpath like `[text()[contains(.,'Inbox (1)')]]`

Comment: Yeah it is the text, would you just add it in after the last forward slash?

Comment: If the text is inside the last a, the xpath will be `//*[@id=':3s']/div/div[1]/span/a[text()[contains(.,'Inbox (1)')]]`. At the a's side, because the text belongs the a

Comment: Hey that's still giving me an error, i'll printout the error I got in my original message, as well as here as I"m not really sure what it means: 

  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:

Comment: TimeoutException inside your wait means that Selenium was not able to find the element using the specified xpath. You should test your xpath in google chrome's console and in the page that you want to select the element, with the expression `$x("your xpath")`

Comment: As you have not posted the html, i can't say why is not finding

Comment: Hey thanks, the chrome console tip worked, i dind't need the id part